# Why $(g\circ f)'=g' \circ f'$ and what's the difference between differential in differential calculus and the usual derivative?

Tags: calculus, differential

A Course in Differential Geometry by Thierry Aubin.
Quote:"Let $f$ be a continuous map of an open set $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{R}^p$...(and $f$ was at least $C^1$)...
Let $g$ be a $C^1$ function of $\theta \in \mathbb{R}^p$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$. Suppose $f(\Omega)\in \theta$, then $g\circ f$  is a $C^1$ function of $\Omega$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ and $(g\circ f)'=g' \circ f'$. "

I kind of understand what does  $(g\circ f)'=g' \circ f'$ mean in multidimensional matrix.

However, when I think about $g,f$ both being one dimension, i.e. scalar functions, then shouldn't $(g\circ f)'()=g'\circ f()\cdot f'()$ according to chain rule?

Why differential and derivative are not consistent even in 1 dimension?

Comment: The total derivative of a map $f:I\subseteq \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is a linear map $Df(x):\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$. Since $\dim \Bbb R=1$, this map is multiplication by a scalar. This scalar is $f'(x)$ from Calculus 1. In other words, the $1\times 1$ matrix representing $Df(x)$ is $(f'(x))$.

Comment: @IvoTerek Yes, that's exactly what I was thinking, but the notation of $g\circ f$ seemed to be "dragged" too much. Consider $g\circ f(x)=g(f(x))$, it's derivative $(g\circ f)'(x)=g'(f(x))f'(x)\neq g'(f'(x))$.

Comment: Yes, you're correct and the book is abusing notation.

Answer (score 1):

Given a (differentiable) function, f(x), the derivative is $f'(x)= \frac{df}{dx}$ is the usual $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)- f(x)}{h}$.  That is NOT a fraction but because it is a limit of a fraction, it can be treated as one.  To make use of that we take "dx" as simply a symbol (but in applications can be treated as a very small number).  Then we define $dy= f'(x)dx$. "dx" and "dy" are the differentials.